# Microsoft Access Query, Matching Values between Columns

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am relatively new to Access SQL. I tried code using the resources online but it shows error every time I tried to run.

I have created the application initially in Excel, it is the Sheet 1

```
Job   Starting Date     Operation              Finish Date   Run Quality 
1     2/3/2019              abc                  5/3/2019          3
1     2/3/2019              bdc                  5/3/2019          3
1     2/3/2019              adc                  5/3/2019          3
1     2/3/2019              edc                  5/3/2019          3
2     3/3/2019              abc                  7/3/2019          4
2     3/3/2019              edc                  7/3/2019          4
2     3/3/2019              adc                  7/3/2019          4
```

I wanted to create similar to this

```
Job   Starting Date abc     bdc        adc   edc    Run Quality     Finish Date
1     2/3/2019      Done    Done       Done  Done    3                5/3/2019
2     3/3/2019      Done    Progress   Done  Done    4                7/3/2019
```

I initially started with few fields

```
Job abc bdc adc edc  Run Quality 
1   abc bdc adc edc     3
2   abc -   adc edc     4
```

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT Job,Operation,Run Quality FROM [OperationTable]
)SRC
PIVOT
(
SUM(Run Quality)
FOR Job IN ([abc],[bdc],[adc],[edc])
)PIV
ORDER BY Job
```

Excel Image 
[image: Input Table & Required Output]
If anyone give their valuable opinion , It would be greatly useful.

Comment: Exactly what data are in Access - just the first table? What criteria determines record is "Done" or "Progress".

Comment: Yes , first table is Available in Access . I want to run a query to get the result . When the abc = abc , bdc = bdc , adc = adc , edc = edc ... when value matches with column heading , it should say as "Done" , when not matching it should say "Progress".

Answer (score 1):

So if a field in CROSSTAB returns Null, show "Progress", otherwise "Done". Consider:

Query1:

```
TRANSFORM First(Table1.Operation) AS FirstOfOperation
SELECT Table1.Job, Table1.StartingDate, Table1.FinishDate, Table1.RunQuality
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Job, Table1.StartingDate, Table1.FinishDate, Table1.RunQuality
PIVOT Table1.Operation In ("abc","bdc","adc","edc");
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Job, StartingDate, FinishDate, RunQuality,
IIf([abc] Is Null,"Progress","Done") AS abcStatus, 
IIf([adc] Is Null,"Progress","Done") AS adcStatus, 
IIf([bdc] Is Null,"Progress","Done") AS bdcStatus, 
IIf([edc] Is Null,"Progress","Done") AS edcStatus
FROM Query1;
```